# Why is my avocado tree’s branch growing more than the main stock?

Tags: tree-care, seedlings, avocado

I have an avocado tree growing from seed and I’m not sure if this side branch needs to be cut or left alone, usually it is just one trunk growing from the seas not the side branch being longer than the main trunk. Help.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the original tip meristem is dead, and the side branch has taken over. Let it grow. The side branch is your new main trunk now.